# Save information in functions | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a game where the user should write answer (the question() function). In the question function I am using variables of 1 and 0 to get the information if the user's answer is wrong or correct. I am also using variables of 1 and 0 to see if the user has answered the questions.

```
def main():
    menu()
    anv_val = ber_val()
    val(anv_val)

def menu():
    print("1. game")
    print("2. stat")
    print("3. end")

def ber_val():
    val = input("Your choice: ")
    while val not in ["1", "2", "3"]:
        print("Print 1, 2 or 3.")
        val = input("Your choice: ")
    return val

def val(anv_val):
    if (anv_val == "1"):
        res = game()
        return res
    elif (anv_val == "2"):
        res = game()
        return stat(res)
    else:
        return end()

def question(quest, solu):
    print(quest)
    answer = input("Your answer: ")
    a_s = 1
    a_f = 0
    while (answer != solu):
        a_f = 1
        print("Try again")
        answer = input("Your answer: ")
    print("Correct!")
    a_f_s = [a_f, a_s]
    return a_f_s

def game():
    a_1 = question("Your name?", "Ricky")
    a_2 = question("Your name?", "Rong")
    a_3 = question("Your name?", "Bolly")
    sum_f = a_1[0] + a_2[0] + a_3[0]
    sum_s = a_1[1] + a_2[1] + a_3[1]
    sum_all = [sum_f, sum_s]
    return sum_all, main()

def stat(res): # Here I get the error message
    print("Questions you answered: " + str(res[1]))
    print("Wrong times: " + str(res[0]))
    return main()

main()
```

Now to my problem. In the function game(), I want to return the variable called a_f_s, AND USE the information (the information is number of error and answered questions) in my function stat(). But the problem is that in the function val(anv_val) - if the user prints "2", the function game() will run, but I want the stat() to run. I am a little bit confused.

I appreciate all the help!